# Error inflating in NavigationView

Tags: android, firebase, navigation-drawer, android-studio-3.1

My App is crashing when android tries to open this activity containing Navigation Drawer.I develop same type of app before but this never happened and now it is happening because i have updated my android studio to 3.1. I tried many StackOverflow previously asked same question which suggests try to use support libraries of same version which i am already doing.
 And the error looks like this as i have shown below. The files that i include below are error log, build.gradle,activity_welcome_drawer and nav_header_welcome. I tried so many solution but nothing helps me.
i am using android studio 3.1 may be issue may be related to that.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.wahdatkashmiri.unknown/com.example.wahdatkashmiri.unknown.Welcome}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2697)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1432)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5912)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.example.wahdatkashmiri.unknown.Welcome.onCreate(Welcome.java:45)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6185)
```

**My **XML code****

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_welcome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_welcome"

       android:background="@color/overlayBackground"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_welcome_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MY build.gradle file**

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.wahdatkashmiri.unknown"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    //adding a customised progress dialog
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
    implementation 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**This is my nav header file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@color/overlayBackground"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFullName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Snow"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />



</LinearLayout>
```

This is activity welcome drawer below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_menu"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:iconTint="@android:color/white"
            android:title="Main Menu" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_cart"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
            android:iconTint="@android:color/white"
            android:title="Cart" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_orders"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_access_time_black_24dp"
            android:iconTint="@android:color/white"
            android:title="Orders" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_sign_Out"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp"
            android:iconTint="@android:color/white"
            android:title="Log Out" />
    </group>


        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />

        </menu>


</menu>
```

Comment: show  `nav_header_welcome` layout and `@menu/activity_welcome_drawer`

Comment: check my edited question @MJM

Comment: Show your Theme

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"> @Shubhamsoni

Comment: Tried removing fitsSystemWindows in NavigationView?

Comment: @ParasSidhu still error

Comment: @WahdatKashmiri If possible, push the code to GitHub and let’s check

Answer (score 0):

Hey Try removing targetSdkVersion in your AndroidManifest.xml